# Failed to get remote.origin.url (task must either be run in a git repository with a configured origin remote or must be configured with the "repo" opt

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I am having this issue with my react website. I've already hosted this website on github pages and I just updated the code and ran "npm run deploy" but it keeps on giving me this error "Failed to get remote.origin.url (task must either be run in a git repository with a configured origin remote or must be configured with the "repo" option)." any idea how to fix this?

```
{
  "homepage": "https://saksham-89.github.io/Portfolio",
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "2",
  "dependencies": {
    "@emailjs/browser": "^3.4.0",
    "@iconscout/react-unicons": "^1.1.6",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "framer-motion": "^6.2.8",
    "git": "^0.1.5",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.6",
    "swiper": "^8.0.7",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0",
    "yarn": "^1.22.19"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same problem while deploying static react application on github pages.

Here is how I resolved it by putting following commands in terminal  :

```
git remote add origin  https://github.com/username/repository_name.git
```

use your username at the place of username

```
git  add ./                        
git commit -m "comment"
```

keep whatever the changes you have made while deploying the page in package.json file . Just because you are getting this error it means that whatever the requirement is there already fulfilled by you.

```
npm run deploy
```

Most IMP :
I was facing this problem just because when linking github with git I was using
origin1 instead of origin .
The react app is only getting deployed for origin while linking git remotely with github.